# Uploading Webcam screenshot with Rails 5 ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading, webcam, rails-activestorage

Like the new ActiveStorage functionality in Rails 5.2.

My app let's the user take a still form their webcam, which I then need to upload as an attachment.
Does anyone know how to do this with ActiveStorage?

My setup accesses the webcam via JS using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia and copies a still to an image tag via a canvas. I've tried uploading the data from the img tag to ActiveStorage, but either ignores it or gives a signing error.

Any ideas if this is possible and how it could be done??
thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interact with a Users webcam & inbuilt microphone using Ruby / Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490613/how-to-interact-with-a-users-webcam-inbuilt-microphone-using-ruby-rails)