# How do you capture a camera image from a website in the .Net world?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, webcam, image-capture

I have an online booking management system that requires images to be captured of the people being booked into the system.  I currently have support for uploading the images manually to the website from a local directory on the client machine (a la Facebook, LinkedIn, etc).  However, I also need to be able for the client to click a button enabling them to use a camera (webcam or otherwise) hooked up to the client machine to take a snapshot and automatically upload it to the server.

The client environment is Windows based, and my development environment is ASP.Net MVC 3.

Are there any 3rd party ActiveX or Flash controls that can do this?

Comment: possible dub http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350594/use-flash-capture-webcam-image

Comment: Check out this blogpost where vamapaull has done this in Flash: http://blog.vamapaull.com/?p=355

Comment: Check out this link ,,, the provided .swf file works well and you could use it in your page to enable users to capture images
[Images from webcam on a page](http://www.tuttoaster.com/create-a-camera-application-in-flash-using-actionscript-3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a 3rd party open-source Flash + JavaScript library that made this fairly simple called '[jpegcam](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/)'.

The following code is built against `Asp.Net MVC 3 (Razor View + T4MVC)`.

---

**Step 1**:  Include the javascript library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jpegcam/htdocs/images.js")"></script>
```

**Step 2**:  Setup jpegcam and wire up the necessary hooks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    webcam.set_api_url('@Url.Action(MVC.Images.Snapshot())');
    webcam.set_swf_url('@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jpegcam/htdocs/webcam.swf")');
    webcam.set_quality(90); // JPEG quality (1-100)
    webcam.set_shutter_sound(false, '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jpegcam/htdocs/shutter.mp3")');
    webcam.set_hook('onComplete', 'upload_complete');

    document.write(webcam.get_html(320, 240));

    function upload() {
        webcam.freeze();  // Snapshot the image from the camera
        webcam.upload();  // POST the data w/ content type 'image/jpeg'
    }
    function upload_complete(response) {
        var json = jsonParse(response);
        if (json.Redirect) {
            window.location.replace(json.Redirect);
        } else if (json.Error) {
            Notifier.Error('Error', json.Error.Message);
            webcam.reset();
        } else {
            Notifier.Error('Error', 'An unknown error has occurred.');
            webcam.reset();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note: The `webcam.set_api_url()` call sets up the POST url.

**Step 3**:  Wire up the buttons in the view

```
<p class="actions">
    <input id="capture-configure" class="secondary-button" type="button" value="Configure..." onclick="webcam.configure()" />
    <input id="capture-submit" class="primary-button" type="button" value="Snap Mugshot" onclick="upload()" />
    <span class="alternate">
        or <a class="cancel" href="@Url.Action(MVC.Images.View())">Cancel</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

**Step 4**:  Create the controller action to service the POST

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Snapshot()
{
    var image = new System.Web.Helpers.WebImage(Request.InputStream);
    // Do fun, amazing things with the jpeg image
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Images.View());
}
```

Note: `System.Web.Helpers.WebImage` is part of the 'microsoft-web-helpers' NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks JD! I used your sample code for my WebForms. I used: `byte[] data = context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.TotalBytes);
File.WriteAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/img/Webcam" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg"), data);` This saves you the 'trouble' of importing microsoft-web-helpers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Silverlight 4 for this? Version 4 comes with support for webcams.

Here's a tutorial at [SilverlightShow.net](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)

Comment: I'm not as confident in Silverlight's longevity on client machines as I am with Flash.  Thinks for the link, though, that was interesting reading!